# Unable to switch from real mode to protected mode in x86 bootloader

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, gnu-assembler, osdev

Ii am creating a bootloader with reference to [this](https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial)

I face two problem regarding it.

1. When I run the code on qemu, it never jumps to 'switch_to_pm' function.
2. When I add '.include load.s' in main.s file , then it gets stuck in `ljmp`.

Can anybody give me some pointers regarding this?

main.s

```
section .data
MSG_PROT:
        .asciz "Protected mode"

.section .text
.global start16
start16:
        mov $0x9000, %bp
        mov %bp, %sp

        mov $'C', %al
        mov $0x0E, %ah
        int $0x10

        call switch_to_pm


.code32
.type BEGIN_PM, @function
.global BEGIN_PM
BEGIN_PM:

        lea MSG_PROT, %ebx
        #call print_string_pm

        . = start16 + 510
        .word 0xaa55
```

load.s

```
.section .data
        .include "gdt.S"

.section .text
.code16
.type switch_to_pm, @function
.global switch_to_pm
switch_to_pm:

        mov $'Z', %al
        mov $0x0E, %ah
        int $0x10

        cli
        lgdt (gdt_descriptor)
        mov %cr0, %eax
        or $0x01, %eax
        mov %eax, %cr0
        ljmp $CODE_SEG, $init_pm


.code32
init_pm:
        lea DATA_SEG, %ax
        mov %ax, %ds
        mov %ax, %ss
        mov %ax, %es
        mov %ax, %fs
        mov %ax, %gs

        mov $0x90000, %ebp
        mov %ebp, %esp
        call BEGIN_PM
```

gdt.S

```
gdt_start:
    .double 0x00000000
    .double 0x00000000

gdt_code:
    .word 0xffff        #segment length or limit 00 -15
    .word 0x0000        #segment base 00 - 15
    .byte 0x00      #segment base 16 - 23
    .byte 0b10011010    # flags (8 bit)
                #   Type : lower 4 bit
                #       from upper (11th bit) to lower (8th bit) in upper byte
                #       1. code : 1 for code segment, since it is code segment
                #       2. conforming : 0 , by not conforming means code in a segment with a lower privilege may not                    #        call code , key to memory protection
                #       3. Readable: 1, if readable , 0 for executable
                #       4. accessed : 0, this is often used for debugging and virtual memory techniques.

                 #  upper 4 bit ( from 15th bit to 11th bit)
                #       1. present : 1 , since segment is present in the memory - used for virtual memory
                #       2. DPL (privilige) : 0, ring 0 represent highestt privilige( occupies 2 bit)
                #       3. Descriptor : 1 for code segment , 0 for data segment

    .byte 0b11001111    # flags (8 bit)
                #   from 16th bit to 23 bit
                #       1. lower 4 bit represent segment limit.
                #       2.  AVL : used for debugging. set it 0
                #       3.  L: set it for 64 bit. 0 , for 32 bit segment
                #       4.  D/b (default operation) : 1, for 32 bit operation, 0 for 16 bit operation
                #       5.  Granularity: 1, if set , this multiplies our limit by 4k, so 0xffff becomes 0xffff000, allowing segment to span 4 gb of memory 
    .byte 0x00


gdt_data:
    .word 0xffff
    .word 0x0000
    .byte 0x00
    .byte 0b10010010
    .byte 0b11001111
    .byte 0x00
gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
    .word gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    .long gdt_start

.equ CODE_SEG, gdt_code - gdt_start
.equ DATA_SEG, gdt_data - gdt_start
```

Comment: Where did you add `.include 'load.s'`?  Your code won't even assemble + link without it; you'd have an undefined reference.  Or if you turn an unlinked `.o` into a flat binary boot sector, then the call target is whatever garbage was there, probably `call rel16=0`.  Single-step your code with a debugger; that's one of the major reasons for having a VM, not just real hardware.  e.g. QEMU+GDB, or better BOCHS's built-in debugger is good for real mode and the switch to protected mode.  Also stuck where / how?  Do you mean `ljmp` faults?  With what exception?

Comment: i tried to link the two files in this manner   ```as main.s -o main.o;   as load.s -o load.o ; ld -Ttext 0x7c00 --oformat=binary -e start16 main.o load.o -o main.bin```

Comment: If you *link* `load.o`, it will be after the end of the 512-byte MBR padding + boot signature so it will never be loaded.  Also, a flat binary doesn't have sections; make sure your `. = _start16 + 510` accounts for the `.data` size as well.  Debug your code live in the VM with a debugger to see what's really in memory after booting; that will reveal mistakes like this.

Comment: Also, your `main.s` doesn't assemble.  It seems you missed the leading `.` in `.section` when copy/pasting.  Hopefully that's the only difference between your question and your real code...

Comment: (I tested; `ld` puts the `.data` section at the end of the flat binary, after the MBR boot signature, so it won't be loaded by the BIOS which only loads the first 512 bytes.  I looked at the `.bin` with `ndisasm`

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the input sir. I will definetly try your suggestions

Comment: Peter pointed out the main problem and as you discovered sections were placed after the boot signature outside the first 512 bytes (first sector). What you really need to do is use a linker script to make sure all the sections are combined before the boot signature is placed on the disk. This linker script `link.ld` should work: https://pastebin.com/GpjJhqL1 . The top of your code will need a `.code16` to ensure you don't generate 32-bit encoding at start. You will need an infinite loop to end things so your kernel doesn't execute whatever is in memory. At the end of 32-bit code put a `jmp .`

Comment: You will also need to remove the padding and the boot signature from main.s. Remove `. = start16 + 510`
        `.word 0xaa55` altogether as the linker script will handle that. Then link with: `ld -Tlink.ld --oformat=binary -e start16 main.o load.o -o main.bin`